# Sorting array of objects in Javascript

Tags: javascript, algorithm, sorting, object, nested-object

I want to sort the data on the basis of the property activeSince but it is not sorted as expected. Here is the code that is being used to sort the data and the data is given as well.

What are the possible ways to do that and is it even possible to sort such type of data structure ?

```js
function sortChatsByActiveSince(filteredData) {
  filteredData.sort((a, b) => {
      if (a.chats.length === 0 && b.chats.length === 0) return 0;
      if (a.chats.length === 0) return  1;
      if (b.chats.length === 0) return -1;

      if (this.sortOrder === "asc") {
        return a.chats[0].activeSince - b.chats[0].activeSince;
      } else {
        return b.chats[0].activeSince - a.chats[0].activeSince;
      }
    });
    for (let data of filteredData) {
      data.chats.sort((a, b) => {
        if (this.sortOrder === "asc") {
          return a.activeSince - b.activeSince;
        } else {
          return b.activeSince - a.activeSince;
        }
      });
    }
    console.log(JSON.stringify(filteredData, null, 2))
}




const filteredData = [
  {
    id: "64e32c286fc5967676d558bc",
    name: "queue",
    chats: [
      {
        name: "jenny",
        identity: "113378945445",
        mediaType: "WEB",
        activeSince: 500,
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: "64e32c146fc5967676d558b2",
    name: "chat 2 queue",
    chats: [
      {
        name: "jenny",
        identity: "113378789",
        mediaType: "WEB",
        activeSince: 900,
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: "64d4d5fe1d7dd34b92f0a7f0",
    name: "chat 1 queue",
    chats: [
      {
        name: "jenny",
        identity: "113311",
        mediaType: "WEB",
        activeSince: 400,
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: "64c90af1eb1d14361be733cf",
    name: "Web Queue",
    chats: [
      {
        name: "jenny",
        identity: "113345624",
        mediaType: "WEB",
        activeSince: 1424,
        timestamp: "2023-08-21T10:58:50.070+00:00",
        agentName: "junaid",
      },
      {
        name: "jenny",
        identity: "11331",
        mediaType: "WEB",
        activeSince: 5396,
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: "64d4dab11d7dd34b92f0a90b",
    name: "chat 3 queue",
    chats: [
      {
        name: "jenny",
        identity: "113378978",
        mediaType: "WEB",
        activeSince: 4644,
        timestamp: "2023-08-21T10:05:10.127+00:00",
      },
      {
        name: "jenny",
        identity: "113378978",
        mediaType: "WEB",
        activeSince: 300,
        timestamp: "2023-08-21T10:05:10.127+00:00",
      },
      {
        name: "jenny",
        identity: "113378978",
        mediaType: "WEB",
        activeSince: 1400,
        timestamp: "2023-08-21T10:05:10.127+00:00",
      },
      {
        name: "jenny",
        identity: "113378978",
        mediaType: "WEB",
        activeSince: 325,
        timestamp: "2023-08-21T10:05:10.127+00:00",
      },
    ],
  },
];

sortChatsByActiveSince(filteredData);
```

I want to sort the whole data on the basis of the property **activeSince** and with this implementation, the nested array is being sorted of each object but not the whole object. Here is the **outPut** of the above implementation.

```
  {
    "id": "64d4dab11d7dd34b92f0a90b",
    "name": "chat 3 queue",
    "chats": [
      {
        "name": "jenny",
        "identity": "113378978",
        "mediaType": "WEB",
        "activeSince": 4644,
        "timestamp": "2023-08-21T10:05:10.127+00:00"
      },
      {
        "name": "jenny",
        "identity": "113378978",
        "mediaType": "WEB",
        "activeSince": 1400,
        "timestamp": "2023-08-21T10:05:10.127+00:00"
      },
      {
        "name": "jenny",
        "identity": "113378978",
        "mediaType": "WEB",
        "activeSince": 325,
        "timestamp": "2023-08-21T10:05:10.127+00:00"
      },
      {
        "name": "jenny",
        "identity": "113378978",
        "mediaType": "WEB",
        "activeSince": 300,
        "timestamp": "2023-08-21T10:05:10.127+00:00"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "64c90af1eb1d14361be733cf",
    "name": "Web Queue",
    "chats": [
      {
        "name": "jenny",
        "identity": "11331",
        "mediaType": "WEB",
        "activeSince": 5396
      },
      {
        "name": "jenny",
        "identity": "113345624",
        "mediaType": "WEB",
        "activeSince": 1424,
        "timestamp": "2023-08-21T10:58:50.070+00:00",
        "agentName": "junaid"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "64e32c146fc5967676d558b2",
    "name": "chat 2 queue",
    "chats": [
      {
        "name": "jenny",
        "identity": "113378789",
        "mediaType": "WEB",
        "activeSince": 900
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "64e32c286fc5967676d558bc",
    "name": "queue",
    "chats": [
      {
        "name": "jenny",
        "identity": "113378945445",
        "mediaType": "WEB",
        "activeSince": 500
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "64d4d5fe1d7dd34b92f0a7f0",
    "name": "chat 1 queue",
    "chats": [
      {
        "name": "jenny",
        "identity": "113311",
        "mediaType": "WEB",
        "activeSince": 400
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: You're first sorting the top level objects by the `activeSince` of the first item, *then* sorting each of the sub-arrays by `activeSince`. Just swap the two blocks of code so the sorting happens in logical order *first* the sub-arrays get sorted, *then* the top-level items get sorted taking into account the top item in `chats`.

Comment: @mplungjan , I swaped the code but still it is not solved. However, it is improved a bit.

Answer (score 1):

The following seems to work as expected. The `sortOrder` is not `"asc"` so it sorts descending. Both within chats. And by conversation.

```js
function sortChatsByActiveSince(filteredData) {
  let isAsc = (this.sortOrder === "asc");

  for (let data of filteredData) {
    data.chats.sort((a, b) => {
      if (isAsc) {
        return a.activeSince - b.activeSince;
      } else {
        return b.activeSince - a.activeSince;
      }
    });
  }
  filteredData.sort((a, b) => {
      let response;
      if (a.chats.length === 0 && b.chats.length === 0) {
        response = 0;
      } else if (a.chats.length === 0) {
        response = 1;
      } else if (b.chats.length === 0) {
        response = -1;
      } else {
        response = a.chats[0].activeSince - b.chats[0].activeSince;
      }

      if (isAsc) {
        return response;
      } else {
        return -response;
      }
    });
    console.log(JSON.stringify(filteredData, null, 2))
}




const filteredData = [
  {
    id: "64e32c286fc5967676d558bc",
    name: "queue",
    chats: [
      {
        name: "jenny",
        identity: "113378945445",
        mediaType: "WEB",
        activeSince: 500,
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: "64e32c146fc5967676d558b2",
    name: "chat 2 queue",
    chats: [
      {
        name: "jenny",
        identity: "113378789",
        mediaType: "WEB",
        activeSince: 900,
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: "64d4d5fe1d7dd34b92f0a7f0",
    name: "chat 1 queue",
    chats: [
      {
        name: "jenny",
        identity: "113311",
        mediaType: "WEB",
        activeSince: 400,
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: "64c90af1eb1d14361be733cf",
    name: "Web Queue",
    chats: [
      {
        name: "jenny",
        identity: "113345624",
        mediaType: "WEB",
        activeSince: 1424,
        timestamp: "2023-08-21T10:58:50.070+00:00",
        agentName: "junaid",
      },
      {
        name: "jenny",
        identity: "11331",
        mediaType: "WEB",
        activeSince: 5396,
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: "64d4dab11d7dd34b92f0a90b",
    name: "chat 3 queue",
    chats: [
      {
        name: "jenny",
        identity: "113378978",
        mediaType: "WEB",
        activeSince: 4644,
        timestamp: "2023-08-21T10:05:10.127+00:00",
      },
      {
        name: "jenny",
        identity: "113378978",
        mediaType: "WEB",
        activeSince: 300,
        timestamp: "2023-08-21T10:05:10.127+00:00",
      },
      {
        name: "jenny",
        identity: "113378978",
        mediaType: "WEB",
        activeSince: 1400,
        timestamp: "2023-08-21T10:05:10.127+00:00",
      },
      {
        name: "jenny",
        identity: "113378978",
        mediaType: "WEB",
        activeSince: 325,
        timestamp: "2023-08-21T10:05:10.127+00:00",
      },
    ],
  },
];

sortChatsByActiveSince(filteredData);
```

Comment: can't we do in the way that sorting is not only confined to the within chats but it is sortedas a whole. What would be the possible ways for that.

Comment: @MuhammadJunaid It WAS sorted as a whole. But I took a guess at what you were objecting to and fixed it. Namely that you want the empty chats to show up where they should based on `sortOrder`. In which case you merely need to make them depend on `isAsc`. If that is right, then lesson for next time. Don't just say "wrong". Say what you would have thought was correct output.